# Проверка на упорядоченность

Tags: java, for

1. Ввестии с клавиатуры 10 слов в список строк.
2. Определить, является ли список упорядоченным по возрастанию длины строки.
3. В случае отрицательного ответа вывести на экран индекс первого элемента, нарушающего такую упорядоченность.

Не понимаю зачем надо применить в цикле условие `i < list.size () - 1;` (здесь 9 итераций)
Почему не просто `i < list.size ();` (здесь будет 10 итераций)
Почему нужны 9 итерации а не 10?

```
package com.javarush.task.task07.task0718;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/* 
Проверка на упорядоченность
*/
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //напишите тут ваш код
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader     (System.in));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String s = reader.readLine ();
            list.add (s);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size ()-1; i++) {
            if(list.get (i).length () > list.get (i+1).length ()){
                System.out.println (i+1);
                break;
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы когда вы достанете 9й элемент, сравнить его с 10, последним элементом. Если достать 10 элемент и сравнить его с 11 - получите ошибку, так как такого элемента нет. Элементов 10, а сравнений достаточно 9

Comment: Где-то я видел подобное. Это не вопрос в тесте одного сайта на проверку квалификации?)

Comment: спасибо – Serhii Dikobrazko